# Naming a REST Endpoint for compiling/mapping/processing data

Tags: rest, asp.net-core-webapi, api-design

I am building a restful api. The appication takes data from the user on the frontend (either from a data form or an uploaded file), sends it to the backend for processing and returns with the processed data. It doesn't save the data or access another resource. What would be a good way to name the RESTful endpoint? The endpoint doesn't access a resource and is more RPC. I have thought of having something like

```
api/compiliations/excel
api/compilations/myinput
```

What would be the best way to name this endpoint?

Answer (score 1):

```
POST /api/compilations/excel
POST /api/compilations/myinput
POST /ea53d835-2298-4a50-bd41-2097b6a8bc33
```

These are all *fine*.  REST doesn't care what spelling conventions you use for your URI.  So choose any spelling consistent with your local conventions that will make things easier for some people (for instance, the operators that need to look at the access logs).